# I need to calculate the Business hours(10:00 Am to 7:00 pm) and with exclude weekends

Tags: formula

I am unable to fetch the elapsed Business Hours and with exclude weekends,

I have tried the below formula, but its useless, so please look at this once and do needful.

```
ROUND( 9 * ( 
( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE( Price_Approval_Date__c) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) + 
MIN(5, 
MOD( DATEVALUE( Price_Approval_Date__c) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7) + 
MIN( 1, 24 / 9 * ( MOD( Price_Approval_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 10:00:00' ), 1 ) ) ) 
) 
) 
- 
( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE( Submission_Date__c ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) + 
MIN( 5, 
MOD( DATEVALUE( Submission_Date__c ) - DATE( 1996, 1, 1), 7 ) + 
MIN( 1, 24 / 9 * ( MOD( Submission_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 10:00:00' ), 1) ) ) 
) 
) 
), 
0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the 10:00 am start time in GMT?  Because the DATETIMEVALUE(1900-01-08 ...) formula expects the start time to be in GMT.  See the appropriate section in [Sample Date Formula](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_examples_dates.htm) page in Salesforce Help.